# How to write multiple join in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am running a spring boot application JPA is behaving very differently depending on the exact circumstances under which it is used. We have created a JPA query when trying to run getting converter type exception issue.

This is what i tried UHG table is not having any foreign key constraint with other tables

```
@Entity
@Table("uhg")
public class UHG {

    @Id
    @Column(name="uhg_no")
    private Integer uhgNo;
    private String section;
    private String area;
    private String zip;
    private String rwd;
    // getter setter
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table("section")
public class Section {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // getter setter
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table("area")
public class Area {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer identifier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="section_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Section section;
    private String name;
    //getter setter
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UHGRepo extends JpaRepository<UHG, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT a.area, b.id FROM UHG a JOIN Section b ON b.name=a.section LEFT JOIN Area c ON c.name=a.area AND c.section.id=b.id WHERE a.section IS NOT NULL AND a.area IS NOT NULL AND c.identifier IS NULL AND a.zip='Ye12Y'")
    List<Area> findAreaSection();
}
```

When calling `findAreaSection()` we are getting ConversionFailedException,
No converter found capable of converting from Type... to other Type...

If I use List<Object[]> findAreaSection();  the query is returning the result.

I believe there is an issue in writing query may be I have not written the join in proper way.

Comment: There are a bunch of IsNull checks you don't need if using inner joins, and I don't see why or how you'd get at an Area with a null identifier; do you mean to look for an Area that doesn't exist; Find the UHG with a section that doesn't have an area? "select yourObjectConstructor(uhg.area, s.id) FROM UHG uhg JOIN Section s ON s.name=uhg.section where uhg.zip = 'Ye12Y' and Not exists (select 1 from Area a where a.section = s)".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the select to another entity that you don´t have.
You need to create a DTO (or POJO) for this query and modify your query.

```
@Repository
public interface UHGRepo extends JpaRepository<UHG, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT new set.your.package.here.QueryResponse(a.area, b.id) FROM UHG a JOIN Section b ON b.name=a.section LEFT JOIN Area c ON c.name=a.area AND c.section.id=b.id WHERE a.section IS NOT NULL AND a.area IS NOT NULL AND c.identifier IS NULL AND a.zip='Ye12Y'")
    List<QueryResponse> findAreaSection();
}
```

You will create this object (QueryResponse for my example) and this object should have a constructor. You need to set the parameters with the required data type in the constructor.

More info here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions

Comment: Hey @Carlos Cárdenas the main problem here is how will i create constructor in Area class because i have one mapping ```many to one``` with section from there i need to set ```section_id```

Comment: @Dell27inch the constructor will be in QueryResponse object. The findAreaSection() will return a List of QueryResponse objects with the provided info.

Answer (score 0):

why not just return c ?

```
@Query("SELECT Distinct c FROM UHG a JOIN Section b ON b.name=a.section LEFT JOIN Area c ON c.name=a.area AND c.section.id=b.id WHERE a.section IS NOT NULL AND a.area IS NOT NULL AND c.identifier IS NULL AND a.zip='Ye12Y'")
    List<Area> findAreaSection();
```

Comment: Original query returns the area and sectionId where there isn't a referenced 'area' of the same name. In this query, 'c' will not exist with a null id, so all its attributes are null.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use @nativeQuery, when you call native query you can write you sql query directly above de method